# python: interpolation for a closed circle

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I want to interpolate a circle by using some given points. I refer to the [scipy.interpolate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#spline-interpolation-in-1-d-procedural-interpolate-splxxx), and use the interpolate.splprep to interpolate my circle. However, the interpolated circle is weird, and it is different from the standard circle:
[image]

And my code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
t = np.arange(0, 1.25, 0.25)
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
y = np.cos(2*np.pi*t)
tck,u = interpolate.splprep([x,y], s=0)
unew = np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.01)
out = interpolate.splev(unew, tck)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'x', out[0], out[1])
plt.axis([-1.05, 1.05, -1.05, 1.05])
plt.title('Spline of parametrically-defined curve')
plt.show()
```

Of course, if I give more points, such as: t = np.arange(0, 1.25, 0.1), the circle would look better. But, I still can not accept this result. Is there any better interpolation method to interpolate the circle?

Fisrt Edit:

@gregory mention that scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline can be used to interpolate a circle. And the example code is:

```
theta = 2 * np.pi * np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
y = np.c_[np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)]
cs = CubicSpline(theta, y, bc_type='periodic')
```

However, it use the theta and [cos, sin] to represent the circle, but what if we do not know the formulation about the curve? What if we only have (x, y)? Can we parametrically represent the curve, like interpolate.splprep?

Comment: scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline seems to do the trick: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html

Comment: Thank you for the kindly answer. However, I am a little confused about how to use this function, and I have edit my question. Could you please have a look at the edit question?

Answer (score 0):

The cubic spline will fit a third degree polynomial to your data, supposedly a circle, and your points are far appart pi/2 radians, so you should consider using more closely spaced data or otherwise, interpolating with polar coordinates. This way your data will be constant radius, turning interpolation unneeded. If you add some noise or pertubation to your data, option bc_type='periodic' just works fine with polar coordinates, as @gregory stated.

Matplotlib (plt) Polar Coordinates:

plt.axes(projection = 'polar')

Coordinates will be angles in radians and a function of (or measured) radius at the corresponding angles.